# Finding difference resullts in subquery returns more than 1 row in mysql error

Tags: mysql

I have a table named tbl_populations having following fields:

```
pk_populationid,residence,value,aspect,gender,fk_tbl_states_stateid
```

I am trying to calculate the difference of rows for two aspects

for e.g.

```
SELECT fk_tbl_states_stateid, value - (
SELECT value
FROM tbl_populations
WHERE fk_tbl_states_stateid = '16'
AND fk_tbl_districts_districtid = '0'
AND residence = '0'
AND gender = '0'
AND aspect = '2' ) AS difference
FROM tbl_populations
WHERE fk_tbl_states_stateid = '16'
AND fk_tbl_districts_districtid = '0'
AND residence = '0'
AND gender = '0'
AND aspect = '1'
```

It is working fine as it returns one row

For fetching multiple data that is i want to retrieve all gender values , i have removed the gender from the condition.

```
SELECT fk_tbl_states_stateid,gender, value - (
SELECT value
FROM tbl_populations
WHERE fk_tbl_states_stateid = '16'
AND fk_tbl_districts_districtid = '0'
AND residence = '0'
AND aspect = '2' ) AS difference
FROM tbl_populations
WHERE fk_tbl_states_stateid = '16'
AND fk_tbl_districts_districtid = '0'
AND residence = '0'
AND aspect = '1'
```

I am getting `Subquery returns more than 1 row` error.

How can i get the all results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Table11.fk_tbl_states_stateid,Table1.Gender,Table1.value - table2.Value as Diff
From
(SELECT *
FROM tbl_populations
WHERE fk_tbl_states_stateid = '16'
AND fk_tbl_districts_districtid = '0'
AND residence = '0'
AND aspect = '2' ) Table1,
(SELECT value,Gender
FROM tbl_populations
WHERE fk_tbl_states_stateid = '16'
AND fk_tbl_districts_districtid = '0'
AND residence = '0'
AND aspect = '1' ) Table2
Where Table1.Gender = Table2.Gender
```

Comment: Thanks romil for answering. This query worked like a charm. thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

use a function for it , should be easy that way

Comment: thanks satya for replying. can you please suggest me a link where i get the reference?

Comment: check this http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3569846/MySQL-Stored-Functions.htm